# How do I stop salesforce continually switching back to lightning experience

Tags: lightning-experience

Every Day I have to switch away from lightning experience.
But I also want access to Lightning as required, without the annoyance factor.

How do I stop this automatic change back to lightning?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Go to Setup / Lightning Experience / Setup Users
Disable: Encourage Users to Stay in Lightning Experience

[image]

Comment: Just a note, that this setup option is only found in lightning experience itself - it is not in the classic setup menu (or at least, it is not in the same place... I couldn't find it there).

Comment: Now it's been hidden even further: Lightning Experience Transition Assistant > Optimize Phase > Motivate Users to Work in Lightning Experience. Or you can create a permission set, enable "Remain in Salesforce Classic" (part of the screenshot above) in the System settings, and assign it to all your friends...